# Passing a variable from one servlet to another servlet

Tags: servlets, parameter-passing

How do I pass a variable `array` from one servlet to another servlet?

Comment: There's just too much information missing in your question. jball's question, whether the servlets are part of the same web app, whether this array is request-specific or just some global data, etc, etc...

Comment: servlets are part of same web app and array is a normal array which has values of some calculations in servlet 1 and has to be passed to servlet 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're passing the *current* request to another servlet, then just set it as request attribute.

```
request.setAttribute("array", array);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/servleturl").include(request, response);
```

It'll be available in another servlet as follows:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) request.getAttribute("array");
```

---

Or, if you're firing a *brand new* request to another servlet, then just set it as request parameters.

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
for (Object item : array) {
    queryString.append("array=").append(URLEncoder.encode(item, "UTF-8")).append("&");
}
response.sendRedirect("/servleturl?" + queryString);
```

It'll be available in another servlet as follows:

```
String[] array = request.getParameterValues("array");
```

---

Or, if the data is too large to be passed as request parameters (safe max length is 255 ASCII characters), then just store it in session and pass some unique key as parameter isntead.

```
String arrayID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.getSession().setAttribute(arrayID, array);
response.sendRedirect("/servleturl?arrayID=" + arrayID);
```

It'll be available in another servlet as follows:

```
String arrayID = request.getParameter("arrayID");
Object[] array = (Object[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(arrayID);
request.getSession().removeAttribute(arrayID);
```

Comment: your solution is best for me. I used the last option.Thanks a lot